# How do I fix this random continuous slow down in Cocos2D 2.1 in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, performance, cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate

I've had a slow down issue since around September when I upgraded my iPad to iOS 7.

Using: Cocos2D 2.1 on iOS 7.1

I've done a lot of testing trying to solve this problem, but so far I cannot find any root cause.

**Some clues**:

- I found if I turn off particles it happens less often, but doesn't
  get rid of it entirely.
- Sometimes it occurs when a scene starts.
- When the slow down happens, the frame rate visibly drops, but the debug frame rate number does not change. It could stay at 60, but it's still slower.
- When the slow down starts, it persists until a new scene is loaded.

A clue that makes me think this may be caused outside of the scene or cocos2D, is that the debug frame rate number does not change. Could it be the way I have my delegate setup?

I pasted the code below. It's kind of a mess because it's been through a lot.

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

#import "ForegroundLabelView.h"

#import "ParallaxCCLayer.h"
@class ParallaxCCLayer;
#import "ColorBGView.h"

@class RootViewController;


@interface cocosTestsAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow            *window_;
    RootViewController  *viewController;
    ForegroundLabelView *foregroundLabelView;

    ParallaxCCLayer *parallaxCCLayer;
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer;
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayerTransition;

    CCDirectorIOS   *director_;                         // weak ref

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ForegroundLabelView *foregroundLabelView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ParallaxCCLayer *parallaxCCLayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CAGradientLayer *bgLayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CAGradientLayer *bgLayerTransition;
@property (readonly) CCDirectorIOS *director;


-(void) resumeGame:(NSTimer *) sender;
-(void) changeColorBGViewWithName:(NSString *)name;
-(void) adjustBGViewPosWithXOffset:(float)xOffset withYOffset:(float)yOffset;
-(void) addBGLayerTransitionWithName:(NSString *)name withXOffset:(float)xOffset withYOffset:(float)yOffset;
-(void) removeBGLayerTransition;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "cocosTestsAppDelegate.h"
#import "GameConfig.h"
#import "BlankScene.h"

#import "RootViewController.h"

#import "ExGlobal.h"


@implementation cocosTestsAppDelegate

@synthesize window=window_, director=director_, viewController, foregroundLabelView, parallaxCCLayer, bgLayer, bgLayerTransition;


- (void) removeStartupFlicker
{
    //
    // THIS CODE REMOVES THE STARTUP FLICKER
    //
    // Uncomment the following code if you Application only supports landscape mode
    //
#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController

    //CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();
    //CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    //CGSize size = [director winSize];
    //CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
    //sprite.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    //sprite.rotation = -90;
    //[sprite visit];
    //[[director openGLView] swapBuffers];
    //CC_ENABLE_DEFAULT_GL_STATES();

#endif // GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController    
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    // Init the window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Try to use CADisplayLink director
    // if it fails (SDK < 3.1) use the default director
//  if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
//      [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];


    //CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];


    // Init the View Controller
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    //viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;

    //
    // Create the EAGLView manually
    //  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
    //  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
    //
    //

//  EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
//                                 pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
//                                 depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
//                      ];

    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];


    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

    //  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:NO] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888]; //kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    //[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];        // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    //[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                 // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    //[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];  // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];

    glView.opaque = NO;
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];


    //
    // VERY IMPORTANT:
    // If the rotation is going to be controlled by a UIViewController
    // then the device orientation should be "Portrait".
    //
    // IMPORTANT:
    // By default, this template only supports Landscape orientations.
    // Edit the RootViewController.m file to edit the supported orientations.
    //
//#if GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//  [director_ setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
//#else
//  [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
//#endif



    //[director setDisplayFPS:[[ExGlobal sharedSingleton] debugState:@"FramesPerSec"]];


    // color/gradient BG

    bgLayer = [ColorBGView createGradientWithName:@"darkCave"];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    [viewController.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];


    // make the OpenGLView a child of the view controller
    glView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    [viewController.view insertSubview:glView atIndex:2];
    viewController.view.opaque = YES;
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    // make the View Controllers childs of the main window
    window_.rootViewController = viewController;


    parallaxCCLayer = [[ParallaxCCLayer alloc] init];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNotificationNode:parallaxCCLayer]; // Layer should be placed here
    [parallaxCCLayer onEnter]; // Schedule for updates



    foregroundLabelView = [[ForegroundLabelView alloc] init];
    foregroundLabelView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    [viewController.view insertSubview:foregroundLabelView atIndex:3];
    foregroundLabelView.hidden = YES;

    [foregroundLabelView release];


    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];




    // Removes the startup flicker
    [self removeStartupFlicker];


    // Run the intro Scene
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [BlankScene scene]];


    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];

}

-(void) resumeGame:(NSTimer *) sender {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}

-(void) changeColorBGViewWithName:(NSString *)name {

    //NSLog(@"RECOLORED ****** %@",name);

    bgLayer = [ColorBGView createGradientWithName:name];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);


    [viewController.view.layer replaceSublayer:[[viewController.view.layer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0] with:bgLayer]; 

}

-(void) adjustBGViewPosWithXOffset:(float)xOffset withYOffset:(float)yOffset {

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.height;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.width;

    CGFloat startX = screenWidth*xOffset;
    CGFloat startY = screenHeight*yOffset;

    //NSLog(@"%f",screenWidth*yOffset);

    //NSLog(@"%f",screenHeight*yOffset);

    [bgLayer removeAllAnimations];
    bgLayer.frame = CGRectMake(startX, startY, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    CGFloat transOffsetX;
    CGFloat transOffsetY;

    if(startX > 0){

        transOffsetX = screenWidth*-1;
        transOffsetY = 0;

    }
    else if(startX < 0){

        transOffsetX = screenWidth;
        transOffsetY = 0;

    }
    else if(startY > 0){

        transOffsetX = 0;
        transOffsetY = screenHeight*-1;

    }
    else if(startY < 0){

        transOffsetX = 0;
        transOffsetY = screenHeight;

    }

    //check needs to be performed to see if frames are still being requested to change
    //even though both x AND y are 0

    if(fabs(xOffset) > 0 | fabs(yOffset) > 0){

        //NSLog(@"moving  *****x=%f y=%f",xOffset,yOffset);

        [bgLayerTransition removeAllAnimations];
        bgLayerTransition.frame = CGRectMake(startX+transOffsetX, startY+transOffsetY, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    }
}

-(void) addBGLayerTransitionWithName:(NSString *)name withXOffset:(float)xOffset withYOffset:(float)yOffset {

    //NSLog(@"ADDED  *****");

    bgLayerTransition = [ColorBGView createGradientWithName:name];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    [bgLayerTransition removeAllAnimations];
    bgLayerTransition.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    bgLayerTransition.zPosition = -1;
    [viewController.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayerTransition atIndex:-1];


}

-(void) removeBGLayerTransition {

    //NSLog(@"REMOVED  *****");

    [bgLayerTransition removeFromSuperlayer];

}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {

    // *** This fixes the frame rate bug when hitting home or making device go to sleep when projecting with kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.00 target:self selector:@selector(resumeGame:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] removeFromSuperview];

    [viewController release];

    [window_ release];

    [director_ end];
}

- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}


// Supported orientations: Landscape. Customize it for your own needs
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

}




- (void)dealloc {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
    [viewController release]; //should i dealloc this?
    [parallaxCCLayer release];
    [window_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What does instruments tell you?

Comment: yes, running Instruments and inspecting allocations as well as time consumption would be a good idea @JodyHagins. Have you tried to run Instruments Vague?

Comment: does it also happen in release builds without debugger attached? do you receive frequent memory warnings?

Comment: I'm not sure what to specifically look for in Instruments for allocations. I do not get memory warnings. I tried running as a release without the debugger, and the issue happened again.